# Prawn 0.11.1 doesn't work with rails 3.0.9

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 app, and I'm using Prawn to generate PDF files.

I have defined this in my controller:

```
Class DocumentosController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @documento = Documento.find(params[:id])
        prawnto :prawn => {
           :left_margin => 20,
           :right_margin => 20
        }
    end
end
```

In my view I have this:

```
<p><%= link_to "Download", documento_path(@docmento, :format => "pdf") %></p>
```

In application.rb I have this:

```
config.gem "prawn"
```

And I get:

```
NoMethodError in DocumentosController#show
undefined method 'prawnto' for #<DocumentosController:0xb6e99358>
```

I try to reinstall the gem, but the problem continuem, and if I try /documentos/6.pdf e.g. the gem generate the PDF but there is an error with the file.

Any idea, which is the problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you fix your problem? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 uses [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) in order to require gems. So you have to add prawn to your Gemfile and then run `bundle install`

Comment: I did, but I get the same problem.

Comment: Are you trying to use this? http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn If yes you have to add the plugin to your gemfile too...